# How to convert a large csv file (~1TB) into a polars dataframe in a shorter time?

Tags: performance, large-files, python-polars

I have a very large CSV file with size 1TB. I want to convert into a polars dataframe, but it takes > ~15mins to generate the dataframe.

How can I do this more efficiently? There are high chances that the size of the file will be bigger, so it might take longer. Is there any efficient way where I can reduce or shorten the computation time?

I have tried to use `n_threads` during polars read csv function, but it still doesnt help much, it managed to reduce by only 1 minute.

```
import polars as pl
csv = pl.read_csv("path to csv file", n_threads=4, ignore_errors = True)
```

Comment: One way is multi processing ...https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/misc/multiprocessing/

Comment: That's not correct. Polars already uses all threads. You shouldn't use multiprocessing. It will be slower.

Comment: @ritchie46 yes it's already multi threaded but if some library or method being single threaded then the other library is the bottleneck, and the problem at hand is parallelizable, it makes sense to use multiprocessing to gain a speed up. ( From doc.)

Comment: @megha add more hardware & utilization information as well.

Comment: OP asks about csv reading in polars, so I don't think we should consider third party libraries.

Comment: @ritchie46 oops you are one of the author of polars!! You may help better, my apologies :)

Answer (score 5):

Polars already parses csv files as fast as it can. It already uses all threads, so trying to spin separate processes will only hurt performance.

You can set `rechunk=False`. That will save an expensive reallocation after reading.

Other things you can try is set the schema to smaller data types, so that you will have less memory and cache pressure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a say on how this file is written, you should go/ask for a parquet file. That will reduce file size and also speed up read, especially if you do not need all columns of the dataset.